# Is the given voltage Peak Voltage or RMS Voltage

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis

> In circuit diagram problems is the labelled voltage RMS voltage
>   or Peak Voltage ?
>
> For example say in problems like this what is the usual convention?
>
> [image: Blockquote]

I recently started learning about circuits and i'm in high school.I don't know if the question is suited for this site or not.But I thought of giving it a try.Do let me know if it's off-topic.

Comment: This is actually a very good question. I don't know if there aren't already duplicates, but if there aren't this certainly belongs here. It is about a central part of the theory in circuit design and analysis, so if there is such a thing it is extremely on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMS should be assumed unless otherwise indicated. In this problem, "effective current" should be assumed to mean RMS current and the supply voltage should be assumed to be 200V RMS.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, it doesn't matter. As long as you consider all the voltages in the circuit to be the same (RMS or peak) (or even peak-to-peak), all your math will work out.

To my knowledge, there is not a well-established convention for this in basic circuits problems. In "real-world" problems, it is dependent on context, but should be labelled clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the "real-world" convention could be to use RMS voltage for this kind of electric circuits. As uint128_t said, here it does not matter since values are going to be calculated with phasorial analysis and not with differential equations.

This eventually will matter when you need to calculate the exactly value of any variable in any specific time, for example how much electrical current is stored into the inductor, in time t. So in that case you will need to use differential equations in the time with sinusoidal analysis and the source voltage should be previously clarified (peak or RMS).

I will highly recommend you the Sadiku's Book, I think it is really good for self learning, go to chapter 9.4 Phasor Relationships for Circuit Elements: http://faculty.weber.edu/snaik/EE2260/alexander_sadiku_fundamentals_of_electric_circuits_4thed.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is rms and if it is peak it is mostly clarified separately to the student.
Also as previously stated the use of term "effective" corresponds to rms value
of parameters of AC circuit.